# Datagridview with SQL connection System.NullReferenceException when adding styling changes to columns

Tags: sql, datagridview, nullreferenceexception, datagridviewcolumn

I am adding code for a DataGridView style change, the connection works fine and displays all the database info (https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hwHH.png) as wel as style changes (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbENc.png)

until I add:

```
dataGridView_ExerciseList.Columns["exerciseprimaryid"].DisplayIndex = 0;
```

or code like:
`this.dataGridView_ExerciseList.Columns["ImplementID"].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;`

I then get "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'" (picture where the exception occurs:[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjR4F.png)

this if for all the code that references a datagridview column with my sql column.
This code actually worked perfectly in another form and I am at a loss as it works in the other form (referencing a different table) and the data does display properly in this form before adding aforementioned code.

other form where code works as intended example:
code:[https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjK9Y.png]
result in windows form app:[https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOYCY.png]

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks in advance and kind regards

Comment: Looks like a column with the specified name  is missing in the `this.dataGridView_ExerciseList.Columns` collection.

Comment: How are the columns added to the grid? If the grid uses a data source and the columns are “AutoGenerated”, then you would need to call that code AFTER the grids data source has been set. Can you clarify how the columns are generated?